# Linq SQL set property values to selected entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Im using Code First Entity Framework and want to set property values of a selected entity within Linq. The problem is that I don't want to create a new entity object by setting every property manually.

I got this Linq:

```
var query = from myEntity in entities.MY_ENTITIES
            join joinEntity in entities.JOIN_ENTITIES on myEntity.JOIN_ID equals joinEntity.ID
            select new MY_ENTITY
            {
                ID = myEntity.Id,
                // all other myEntity properties that I want to avoid setting manually
                NotMappedProperty = joinEntity
            };
```

But instead of creating a new `MY_ENTITY` object I just want to set the NotMappedProperty of `myEntity` within the select.
Also I cannot map the two tables because my join is more complex and not really mappable.

Any idea on how to reduce the code instead of writing each property set manually? This can really blow up if you got an entity with many properties.

---

A solution would be to create a wrapping object, but that doesn't seem right:

```
public class MY_ENTITY_EXTENDED
{
    public MY_ENTITY MyEntity { get; set; }

    public JOIN_ENTITY JoinEntity { get; set; }
}
```

And in the Linq select:

```
// ...
select new MY_ENTITY_EXTENDED
{
    MyEntity = myEntity,
    JoinEntity = joinEntity
}
```

Comment: There is NO way to do update while selecting. Select is ONLY select. When you write select in LINQ, it is "translated" into SQL SELECT. Not INSERT, not UPDATE. Only SELECT. For updating data you can look here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/crud-operation-in-connected-scenario-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: @HemidAbbasov I don't want to update the entity at all, I just want to set the `NotMappedProperty` to the joined entity to my local(!) generated objects. That's why the property is not mapped.

Comment: I'd make two queries then loop through the list of MY_ENTITIES returned by first query, finding and setting the NotMappedProperty to the relevant entry in the list of entities retrieved from JOIN_ENTITIES.

Comment: Why doesn't MY_ENTITY have a navigation property to JOIN_ENTITY?

Comment: @JeffDavies That solution is probably a little bit slower, but did the trick. If you write an answer with a simple example, I can mark it as answer

Comment: @GertArnold The mapping I would need is not supported

Comment: ok have added the solution @Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel,
something like this should work, where the joined entity is filled after returning the original set of entities:

```
var list = new List<MY_ENTITY> ();

var query = from myEntity in entities.MY_ENTITIES 
            select new MY_ENTITY
            {
                ID = myEntity.Id,
                // all other myEntity properties that I want to avoid setting manually
                NotMappedProperty = null,  //    --> we will set this later
                joinEntityIdToJoinTo = joinEntity.ID
            };;

var joinedObjectsQuery = from myEntity in entities.JOIN_ENTITIES;

foreach (var entity in query) 
{
    list.Add( new MY_ENTITY {
        ID = entity.ID,
        NotMappedProperty = joinedObjectsQuery.Single(x=>xID == entity.joinEntityIdToJoinTo)
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using partial classes would allow you to extend the MY_ENTITY class.

E.g.

```
public partial class MY_ENTITY
{
   // db entity properties
}

public partial class MY_ENTITY
{
    public JOIN_ENTITY JoinEntity { get; set; }
}
```